# Subscriber stuck in 2GP Package version

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, package-install, ancestor

I have the following branching for a package (2gp) ancestry.

[image: sfdxAncestryTree]

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_package_ancestor_intro.htm), it seems like 5.72 is a dead branch, and we have plenty of customers using 5.72 at the moment.

[image: branchingReview]

Is there a way to avoid uninstalling the application to update to 5.74? We have a lot of customers that would mandatorily have to go through using Dataloader in numerous environments if that's not possible.

Comment: I don't think it is ever possible to merge version tree branches, so you are left with either doing what you suggested with data export, uninstall, new install, data import, for this branch OR treat 5.73/5.74 as the dead branch and migrate the installs of these over to a new version based off 7.72 (that has the same content as 5.74, if that is possible).

Answer (score 1):

*Mostly pulling Phil W's comment into a real answer:*

Your customers are on a Package Version, which Salesforce calls an **abandoned version** and in the wisly-labeled Section  **"With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility"** the say:

> If abandoned versions [..] are installed in customer orgs, those
> customers no longer have an upgrade path.

I recommend simply not using non-linear versioning on Production-Packages until you have long experience experimenting with internal playground packages.